# How To Retrieve/Parse Query String Parameters with NodeJS Built in node:querystring?

Tags: node.js, query-string

Is there any simple way to directly make use of node built-in tool to parse the query string parameter in nodeJS instead of installing extra package?

I have seen that there is a built in node module "node:querystring".

However when using it, it does not work as exactly what expected:

```
const url = 'https://www.test.com/?utm_campaign=1%25+LAL&utm_content=Test+Video&fbclid=s3XjT0ggIZq6o'

require('node:querystring').parse(url)
```

Result:

```
{
  'https://www.test.com/?utm_campaign': '1% LAL',
  utm_content: 'Test Video',
  fbclid: 's3XjT0ggIZq6o'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The querystring module is designed to parse **query strings**, not URLs. In your example, the parse method is treating the entire URL as the query string and parsing it accordingly, which is why you're getting these results.

To parse the query string parameters in your URL, you'll need to extract *just the query string* portion of the URL and pass that to the parse method. You can do this using the node:url module:

```js
const url = require('node:url');
const querystring = require('node:querystring');

const myUrl = 'https://www.test.com/?utm_campaign=1%25+LAL&utm_content=Test+Video&fbclid=s3XjT0ggIZq6o';
const queryString = url.parse(myUrl).query;

const parsedQuery = querystring.parse(queryString);

console.log(parsedQuery);
```

with the following output

```js
{
  utm_campaign: '1% LAL',
  utm_content: 'Test Video',
  fbclid: 's3XjT0ggIZq6o'
}
```

Sidenote: the `querystring` module does **not** decode URL-encoded characters by default, so the "%25" in your query string is not automatically decoded to a percent sign. If you want to decode URL-encoded characters, you can pass the `decodeURIComponent` function as the second argument to `querystring.parse`:

````js
const parsedQuery = querystring.parse(queryString, null, null, { decodeURIComponent: decodeURIComponent });```
````